# Azure: Running a non-web-app in a Linux containers in Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

My Linux container does not have a web-server running (it's doing background work at some intervals). It's running perfectly on my developer box. However on Azure I an error:

> ERROR - Container xxxx for site yyyy did not start within expected
>   time limit. Elapsed time = 230.1049404 sec

I think this is caused by Azure checking if a website has been started. My question is: Is it possible to disable this check - so that I can have a non-web-app running in my container?

Comment: Check out this [Hanselman blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudDeployingContainersCheaplyToAzure.aspx) for a quick primer on container service options on Azure.

Comment: You can just add a "Hello world" to it. That might be cheaper if you just want to use some spare capacity on an app service plan you already purchased for other reasons. If not, then go with other hosting options as mentioned below.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the wrong service for that. App Service requires that you expose an HTTP-speaking endpoint.

Look at [**Azure Container Instances**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) instead, or a 2-node [**AKS**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) cluster. You can do away with a single node cluster if HA isn't top of your list. Both services can expose TCP ports that can speak raw bytes (or whatever protocol those bytes amount to - MQTT, AMQP, YouNameIt).